# empty css file after pushing to heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I don't know much of rails.

The app runs well locally, but when I deploy, I don't have any `css` loaded, in fact I can see in my console an `application` `css` file in the `assets` folder but it is empty.

I use `bootstrap-sass` gem, and in my `application.css.scss`file, I call `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"`and `@import "bootstrap";`.  Following some blog post, I tried to `rake` precompile the assets but with no change. Can someone help

Comment: Before deploying, try running with the environment variable set so it compiles the proper resources: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: @DivXZero that's what I did. Finally, since I was working on a pre existing project, I rebuild it from the ground, adding gems one after the other and it finally worked, without knowing what as precisely the problem, however I suspect that reporting the import of `bootstrap` from the `application.css.scss` to some other `.scss` file corrected the problem